# redrawing a Rect that created via a class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

One of the aspects of my app is drawing a pie chart.  So once the user tap a button i initiate a pieDrawing class that i created.

```
mPieClass=[[PieClass alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10+PosX, 10, 320, 230)];
```

then i fill some data to the class variables, radius,colors,values etc (and the class itself create some labels)
and then add it as subview.

```
[self.view addSubview:mPieClass];
```

so far so good and the pie is showing fine. Now due to changing the iPad orientation i need to redraw it and place it in a different location.

my question is how should i go doing that, currently i just call the drawing/creating method again and it will draw another pie in a different location, but my previous pie is still showing. I thought that if i call

```
 mPieClass=[[PieClass alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10+PosX, 10, 320, 230)];
```

it will redraw it elsewhere using the new value of PosXand it does but the old pie is still there.
Do i need to dealloc or something to clear the old pie?

Let me know if you need more detail.
Thanks

Comment: What is `PieClass` a subclass of? You can probably just do `[self.view removeSubview:mPieClass]` before you redraw and re-add.

Comment: @Dustin the PieClass is subclass of my main View, it's the parent view of all subviews i have. I tried your code initially and i get a warning "Instance method -removeSubview not found (return type default ti ID) "  and when i run the code it blows SIGABRT

Comment: I declared PieClass *mPieClass;     as a global\public variable at the top view controller.m  code..

Comment: Oops I forgot that `UIView` doesn't have a `removeSubview` method. Call `[mPieClass removeFromSuperview]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `UIView` documentation:

> The *frame* defines the origin and dimensions of the view in the
>   coordinate system of its superview and is commonly used during layout
>   to adjust the size or position of the view.

To place your view at a new position you assign a new frame:

```
mPieClass.frame = CGRectMake(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight);
```

Comment: you are correct! And i did that so many times directly on other UI objects. for what ever reason i wasn't aware i can do it on the frame via the class. Thank a bunch.